# Call a method twice or create a temp variable?

Tags: php

I got to wondering about the efficiency of this:

I have a csv file with about 200 rows in it, I use a class to filter/break up the csv and get the bits I want. It is cached daily.

I found that many descriptions (can be up to ~500 chars each) have a hanging word "Apply" and it needs chopping off.

Thinking that calling `toString()` on my object more than once would be bad practice, I created a temp var : `$UJM_desc` (this code is inside a loop)

```
// mad hanging 'Apply' in `description` very often, cut it off
$UJM_desc = $description->toString();

$hanging = substr($UJM_desc, -5);

if($hanging == "Apply")
    $UJM_desc = substr($UJM_desc, 0 , -5);


$html .= '<p>' . $UJM_desc ;
```

But could have just called `$description->toString()` a couple of times, I am aware there is room to simplify this maybe with a ternary, but still, I froze the moment and thought I'd ask.

Call a method twice or use a temp var? Which is best?

Comment: Depends.  What type of object is `$description` and how complicated is the `toString()` method?  Secondly, you could do something like `$html .= '<p>' . preg_replace('/Apply$/', '', $description->toString());` and call it a day.

Comment: The answer depends on how many times the function is being called and how important the time saved is.  If saving 100ms isn't a big deal, then it may not be worth the time trying to prematurely optimize the code.

Comment: Where does the csv file come from? Solving the actual problem (if possible...) seems a better idea than cleaning up the results afterwards. And even if you need to clean up afterwards, if the file is cached daily, I would use a cronjob to clean up the file once instead of doing it every time when the output is requested.

Comment: @GigaWatt $description is another object the data is passed to in order to do some text transformations (auto-links etc).  I might extend that class and make it specific to this domain, chop off the word there - I was thinking there could be others. Else, preg_replace() I guess is the simplest/cleanest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use regex to strip off the end:

```
$html .= '<p>' . preg_replace('/Apply$/', '', $description->toString());
```

That said, if `$description->toString()` gives the same output no matter where you use it, there's absolutely no reason to call it multiple times, and **a temporary variable will be the most efficient**.

There's also no reason to save `$hanging` to a variable, as you only use it once.

Comment: would need to benchmark against his string to know for sure, but his current `substr` will almost certainly be faster than `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends, and it's a tradeoff.

Keeping a calculated value in a variable takes up memory, and runs the risk of containing stale data.

Calculating the value anew might be slow, or expensive in some other way.

So  it's a matter of deciding which resource is most important to you.

In this case, however, the temporary variable is so short-lived, it's definitely worth using.